# How do I update/reload beans server side after ajax events?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm trying to set up a Timeline (primefaces element), to display an agenda.
Each line is a colleague, with an object "Identite" I created.
Each event is an object "EventPlanning" I created as well, only associated with one person, therefore on a single line.

Identite & EventPlanning objects are read from a mySQL base, with associated two tables.

On my timeline, I implemented a way to create a new event, then to persist it in the table. Problem is, I can't find how to update the timeline server side, even following this example :
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/editServer.xhtml?jfwid=3715a

What's happening :

- User Interface is properly updated, but anybody connecting from an other computer will not see newly added events.
- New event is properly created and inserted into DB, but it needs a new launch of the application on the server to see it everywhere.

### Here is the main xhtml page :

```
    <div class="card">
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:growl id="growl" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" keepAlive="true" life="3000">
                <p:autoUpdate/>
            </p:growl>
        
                <p:timeline id="timeline" styleClass="friseChrono" value="#{friseTemporelle.model}"
                            editable="true" eventMargin="10" eventMarginAxis="0"
                            start="#{friseTemporelle.start}" end="#{friseTemporelle.end}"
                            stackEvents="false" zoomMin="#{friseTemporelle.zoomMin}"
                            zoomMax="#{friseTemporelle.zoomMax}">                    
                    <p:ajax event="add" update="newEventInner"
                            listener ="#{friseTemporelle.onAdd}"
                            oncomplete="PF('newEventWdgt').show()"/>
                    <p:ajax event="changed" listener ="#{friseTemporelle.onChanged}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="edit" listener ="#{friseTemporelle.onEdit}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="delete" listener ="#{friseTemporelle.onDelete}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="select" listener ="#{friseTemporelle.onSelect}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rangechanged" listener ="#{friseTemporelle.onRangeChanged}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="lazyload" listener ="#{friseTemporelle.onLazyLoad}"/>
                </p:timeline>
            
            
                <p:dialog id="newEventDlg" header ="Ajouter nouveau" widgetVar="newEventWdgt">
                    <h:panelGroup id="newEventInner" layout="block">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="newColonne1,newColonne2">
                            <h:outputText value="Position" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{friseTemporelle.currentEvent.data.valeur}"
                                         rendered="#{not empty friseTemporelle.currentEvent}"
                                         required="true" label="Position"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="text-align:right; padding:2px; white-space:nowrap;">
                            <p:commandButton value ="Save" process="newEventDlg" update="@none"
                                             action="#{friseTemporelle.saveNewEvent}"
                                             oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed){PF('newEventWdgt').hide();}"/>
                            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Close" onclick="PF('newEventWdgt').hide()"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </div>
```

---

Here is the class FriseTemporelle I use to implement a timeline as a bean :

---

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class FriseTemporelle implements Serializable {
private TimelineModel<EventPlanning,Identite> model;
private LocalDateTime start, end;
private long zoomMin, zoomMax;
private TimelineEvent <EventPlanning> currentEvent; //current event to be changed, edited, deleted or added

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() { long skipped code }

public void onAdd(TimelineAddEvent e) {
    currentEvent = TimelineEvent.<EventPlanning>builder()
            .id(e.getId())
            .data(new EventPlanning())
            .startDate(e.getStartDate().toLocalDate())
            .endDate(e.getStartDate().toLocalDate().plusDays(1))
            .editable(true)
            .group(e.getGroup())
            .build();
    model.add(currentEvent);
    }

public void saveNewEvent() {
    EventPlanning nouvelEvent = new EventPlanning(currentEvent.getData().getValeur(), groupMap.get(currentEvent.getGroup()), Date.valueOf(currentEvent.getStartDate().toLocalDate()));
    eventPlanningDAO.save(nouvelEvent);

    TimelineUpdater timelineUpdater = TimelineUpdater.getCurrentInstance(":form:timeline");
    model.update(currentEvent, timelineUpdater);
}
```

---

I skipped getters, setters, and other listeners

I think there's something I'm missing about JSF ...
Any idea what it is ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

Found it ! My class had to be @ApplicationScoped :)

Comment: Promoting the bean scope to `@ApplicationScoped` is usually not the solution. In fact, you might have introduced a huge security flow in your application.

Comment: Ok, what is the usual solution then ?My objective is to be able to edit the planing from any computer on the network, and the changes to be seen on the others after refresh.